# Can I download .aspx.vb file from website?

Tags: asp.net

I am beginner at asp.net. I just want to know is there any way where can someone download aspx.vb or .aspx file from web server? I was searcing for answer but I didn't got any answers... Regards

Answer (score 1):

If you'll open `IIS Manager` > `Request Filtering` > `File Name Extensions` you'll notice that `.vb` extension is not allowed (hence not served, as well as many other non-standard file name extensions).

(Applies to IIS 7.0 and above)

Answer (score 0):

Let me understand your question first. Do you mean whether people can download the source code that you've written in ASP.NET, if you have it up on your site? The answer is no, the web server will render the site, and that's what is going to be presented to the user.

Comment: Yes that was my question. I noticed on my friend website that there is .aspx.vb files. So I just want to clarify that. Ty